# AWS S3 error with PFFiles after importing the exported Parse data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parse-platform

Looks like Parse.com stores the PFFile objects on AWS S3 and only stores a reference to the actual files on S3 in Parse for the PFFile object types.

So my problem here is I only get a link to AWS S3 link for my PFFile if I export the data using the out of the box Parse.com export functionality. After I import the same data to my Parse application, for some reason the security setting on those PFFiles on S3 is changed in a way that all PFFiles won't be accessible to me after an import due to security error.

My question is, does anyone know how the security is being set on the PFFiles? Here's a link to PFFile https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFFile.html but I guess this is rather an advanced topic and wasn't revealed on this page.

Answer (score 0):

Also looking a solution for this, all I found is this from their forum:

> In this case, the PFFiles are stored in a different app. You might
>   need to download these files and upload them again to the new app and
>   update the pointers. I know this is not a great answer but we're
>   working on making this process more straightforward.

https://www.parse.com/questions/import-pffile-object-not-working-in-iphone-application