# How can I move a Parse PFFile from one application to another?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pffile

I need to move image data stored in one Parse application (Source database)  to another Parse application (Client). The PFFile was created using an IOS application in the Source. I have a choice of redoing this from the Client app using the original images but this is cumbersome. I saw the following discussion in the link below but it is not clear what it means to "download" as suggested in the discussion.

[exporting pffile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684200/aws-s3-error-with-pffiles-after-importing-the-exported-parse-data)

Answer (score 0):

The referenced answer still stands true. Exporting and importing files with a click of a button is not supported as of now.

You would have to download them and then re-upload them, one by one, to the app you want to copy them to.

Comment: The part that I don't understand is whether I download from the Parse console or I build that into the Source app. If I export the class that contains the PFFile from the Source and then try importing into the Client the PFFile is not processed properly as suggested in the discussion. So, what am I downloading? Should I write the images to a file from Source and read them from Client?

Comment: Now I am confused, do you want to move the files between two different Parse apps OR do you want to download files from Parse to your phone for example? Your use of tyhe server/client terminology confuses me a bit here

Comment: The Source manages the images (adds, deletes, resizes) and then I want to make the transformed images avail to Client for display. Right now both programs are on ios but my objective is that the Source will be on IOS with Parse as the Backend and the Client programs would exist for Android or IOS the Client programs with their own backends that do other activities. I want Clients to be able to get the images from the Source. I have not tried accessing two Parse backends from a single Client but if I knew how, that would also work. Main objective is to have a single shared img-database.